# notification on different notification channel on different alert condition of same GCP metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have to create an alert on CPU utilization metric of a VM in GCP and it must follow the below condition:

- first notification will send to **email** when threshold >50%
- second notification will send to **mobile** when threshold >80% (kind of escalation over mobile).

is it possible via GCP stackdriver monitoring.?

Answer (score 1):

An alerting policy describes a set of conditions that you want to monitor. These conditions might relate to the health of an application, the value of a system metric, or to resource consumption. The conditions for an alerting policy define what is monitored and when to trigger an alert.

For example, suppose you want to define an alerting policy that emails you if the CPU utilization of a Compute Engine VM instance is above 50% for 3 minutes. You use the conditions dialog to specify that you want to monitor the CPU utilization of a Compute Engine VM instance, and that you want an alerting policy to trigger when that utilization is above 50% for 3 minutes.

**According to your use case you will need to create two alerting policies on the same GCP metric, because your use case contains two different alert conditions with different notification channels.**

**1.** Create an Alert policy that will send you an alert to email when threshold>50%.

- In the Cloud Console, select Monitoring
- Select Alerting.
- Click Create policy.
- Click Add Condition in the Create new alerting policy window.

[image]

- In the threshold condition, you can add a percentage.
  [image]
- Click on save, now you can add notification channels, click on manage notification channels and add mail notification channels. Refer [manage notification channels](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) for more information.
  [image]

**2.** Repeat the same process to create an Alert policy that will send you an alert to mobile when threshold>80%, you can select an SMS notification channel while selecting notification channels.

Refer [Create an alert policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#create-policy) and [Specifying conditions for alert policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/ui-conditions-ga) for information.

Comment: So, I have to create 2 alert policy for same metric with different alert condition and notification channel.

Comment: Yes @dushyant, you will need to create 2 alert policies for same metric

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** This is possible by creating 2 alert policies to meet your 2 conditions.

First, create an alert policy that will send to **email** when threshold >50%.
Second, create an alert policy that will send to **mobile** when threshold >80%.

Please see [GCP - Using alerting UI](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui) for creation of Alert Policy and [GCP - Notification Options](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) for the options for the notification which includes *Email* and *Mobile (SMS)*.

Comment: is this not possible with single alert policy .

Comment: @dushyant No, since you have 2 different conditions with 2 different notification channels.